# Struggling with Mobile First Responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, user-experience

I seem to be struggling with "mobile first" design. From the impression I got from reading many articles and the Mobile First (2011) book it's a processes of creating your mobile site first before the desktop version.

It makes sense in what's being discussed and I like the idea.

But, what does this mean in terms of development? Do I style my default site as "mobile". i.e. no media queries are involved in design the mobile version, this is the default layout. Media queries are only used to progressively enhance the user experience as their screen resolution or width becomes greater. In which case media queries are then used to target these devices.

Another issue is the term responsive. I understand what this means very well, but in a mobile first approach, a responsive grid isn't going to make much sense because my layout for phones at least, is going to be significantly different from tablets and desktop.

I can see the use of a responsive grid being used from tablet to desktop, or vice versa, because the fluid grid can scale, but much of the content on phones won't look well scaled, so many elements would be positioned vertical.

Also, what about adding content that doesn't appear on phones? Is this done by hiding the content? And how does this affect SEO? Or are other tricks used to add more content to devices with bigger device widths? Like using PHP to determine the device width and serving content suitable for that device?

And finally, the loading of scripts and resources. If I'm developing mobile first, how do I go about including resources for desktops where bandwidth and page size isn't an issue when compared with mobile devices. Is this a case for something like yepnopejs?

I'm struggling to get my head around the actual development processes and doing things the correct way which conform to conventions.

Comment: Is there an actual programming problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have heard of all sorts of programming wizardry to effectively transition between scales, some seem to sound more efficient than others. I think it will become more and more the norm as phones begin to out-browse computers and companies need to focus more on their mobile sites. I personally believe it is a far more difficult process as you have to implement key features into your mobile site while kind of pre-planning more extensive features to be used on desktop and tablet sites, kind of like trying to build a pyramid upside down or something. Whatever works, like I say, I believe the demand and the money will be shifting to mobile sites in the near future though, so I can understand the Mobile First idea. Honestly, converting between formats will always be a pain and will always be whatever is most comfortable to the designer.

Comment: Your last sentence is my feeling exactly. But the way many articles describe the process is as if it's painless and easy - such as Zurb's Foundation 4 framework. They make out that a grid system that collapses is all you need when in reality it isn't because phone UI's tend to be different to tablet and desktop (although the can look the same, I don't think it's always a good idea).

Comment: By the way, in some cases, mobile usage already outweighs desktop usage. Such as the example on one of my sites. I have a lot more mobile devices accessing the site than desktop users.

Comment: It is crazy that it is getting to that point, but I am confident in the near future the majority of sites will get the bulk of their traffic from phones and tablets. It is funny how they try to make it sound like it is as simple as setting up a simple grid when it is vastly more complex. I have had trouble finding any good tips on really doing this effectively, like I say it just seems like a difficult process to me.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to create a responsive design first you need to plan your site very carefully and i think you should create your website from desktop to tablet then to mobile you can control what is being loaded by using media queries

Comment: Well this is the problem. I develop sites in niches where users are using a mobile device for 68% of the traffic (statistics from a current site I run) so desktop users are the minority. So designing from the desktop down in today's era, would be like saying "design from mobile first" back in 2006. I really need to think about mobile users first.

Comment: The wisdom is to pare down your content for *mobile first* because that creates focus on the most important elements. Successive natural breakpoints then bring in extra material, enhancements, etc. Here's a nice [real-world example with reasons why](http://www.wearejh.com/design/benefits-of-a-mobile-first-approach/).